# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android

I've looked trough all of the other questions titled `Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo` (and there are lots of them!) but I couldn't find the right fix for my problem. And that's why I'm asking this question again.

So, after forking a project from `GitHub` and customising the source code, I've finally completed my app, but sadly it's not working when launching it on my device (Nexus 7 2012). Logcat throws me the following error:

```
   0227 23:10:49.182: D/dalvikvm(23626): Late-enabling CheckJNI
   0227 23:10:49.242: W/dalvikvm(23626): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/nerdability/android/ArticleListActivity; (17)
   0227 23:10:49.242: W/dalvikvm(23626): Link of class 'Lcom/nerdability/android/ArticleListActivity;' failed
   0227 23:10:49.242: D/AndroidRuntime(23626): Shutting down VM
   0227 23:10:49.242: W/dalvikvm(23626): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41837ba8)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626): Process: com.nerdability.android, PID: 23626
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.nerdability.android/com.nerdability.android.ArticleListActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nerdability.android.ArticleListActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nerdability.android-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.nerdability.android-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.nerdability.android.ArticleListActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nerdability.android-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.nerdability.android-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
   0227 23:10:49.242: E/AndroidRuntime(23626):  ... 11 more
```

I have absolutely no idea why it's saying 'didn't find class' even though everything that is required for the app to run is there. I'm pretty new to Java and Android Development, so I'm sure that I'm asking a stupid question...

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nerdability.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/rssicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ArticleListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_article_list" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.nerdability.android.ArticleDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_article_detail" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".ArticleListActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**ArticleListActivity**: http://pastebin.com/x8D0ZMch

Comment: I have the same problem, no idea why...

Comment: I managed to fix it eventually, but I don't remember how exactly. I'm so sorry! :(

Comment: I fixed it too. In my case the problem was tha way I was referencing the support libraries

Comment: is the rss reader from nerdability example for rss workin? in my case is returning always null for the articles list...¿Does any know about it?